# Resetting Data Layer variables in Single page Applications ( Google Tag manager)

Tags: single-page-application, google-datalayer

Trying to achieve content grouping in mobile site which is SPA.

**The scenario goes like this**: When I am visiting a PDP page for the first time, category variable is set and this is sent to content groups in Universal Analytics Tag.
If after this I go back to the homepage, the category variable doesn't update and homepage is also grouped under the same content group of previous PDP page.

This variable only updates when I visit another PDP page.

I am using a custom event PageLoad to mimic the pageView event. Just want the data layer varaibles to refresh within the consecutive PageLoad event.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to update that variable for every pageview?

Comment: Yes thats what I am looking for .... but not sure how to do it. Can this be done via firing a Tag through GTM using dataLayer.push

Comment: Yes, it can be done with custom HTML tag. But it is much better to push data to dataLayer from backend.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a documented way to reset the data layer. See [Reset](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/datalayer#reset) in the Data layer docs.

If you push a function to the `dataLayer`, it'll give you access to an object with `get`, `set`, and `reset` semantics. For this question in particular, `reset` is the relevant bit.

Comment: I have to say, this is more than perfect. It amazing, thanks for this. This is specially useful when dealing with many variables

Answer (score 4):

There's an undocumented way to cleanup the whole dataLayer using this method:

```
var gtm = window.google_tag_manager['GTM-XXXXXX'];
gtm.dataLayer.reset();
```

Now you don't necessarily need to do that since you can set the values you don't want anymore to `undefined` in your dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'please_go_away': undefined
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If the `reset()` doesn't work for you, maybe you want to try the following code

```
const boomDataLayer = () => {
  if (window.dataLayer !== undefined && window.google_tag_manager !== undefined) {
    window.dataLayer.length = 0;
    const gtmContainerReg = /GTM-/i;

    for (const gtmKey of Object.keys(window.google_tag_manager)) {
      if (gtmContainerReg.test(gtmKey) && window.google_tag_manager[gtmKey].dataLayer
        && window.google_tag_manager[gtmKey].dataLayer.reset
      ) {
        window.google_tag_manager[gtmKey].dataLayer.reset();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/datalayer#reset did not work. This one worked.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
export const dataLayerPush = payload => {
  if (window.dataLayer) {
    window.dataLayer.push(function() {
      this.reset();
    });
    window.dataLayer.push(payload);
  }
};
```